# Как сделать выборку по дате из текстового поля

Tags: php, mysql

У меня таблица в формате (поле с типом `text`):

```
+------------------+
|       data       |
+------------------+
| 23.06.2015 10:30 |
| 24.06.2015 10:45 |
| 26.06.2015 12:15 |
| 02.07.2015 11:24 |
+------------------+
```

Если ищу между датами, то находит неправильно. Только если ищу по одному месяцу, допустим по июню, если ищу с июня по июль, то ничего не выводит.

Такой запрос:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `selling_list` WHERE
 `data`>'22.06.2015' AND `data`<'03.07.2015'");
```

выдаст пустой результат. а такой:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `selling_list` WHERE
 `data`>'22.06.2015' AND `data`<'30.06.2015'");
```

выдаст 3 результата.

Почему так? Как правильно сделать выборку?

Comment: ``data`>'22.06.2015'` Это сравнение со строкой. Используйте функции для конвертации дат и оператор `BETWEEN`

Comment: @u_mulder можно небольшой пример, в ответ? А я закреплю как правильный ответ.

Comment: Хотел бы добавить - это же PHP, гораздо удобнее хранить дату и время в UNIX формате. По крайней мере в крупных проектах так и делают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если дата в строке указана в [понятном](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html) серверу `mysql` формате, то диапазон можно указывать, например, так:

```
select ... where data between "2015-06-20" and "2015-07-03";
```

но у вас ситуация осложняется тем, что в базе данных содержится, во-первых, строка, а не дата, а во-вторых в «непонятном» серверу формате.

значит, надо преобразовывать строку при выборке с помощью функции [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), указав вторым параметром подходящий [шаблон](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

пример (в выборку попала дата за 23 июня и не попала за 2 июля потому, что если не указано время, то оно берётся как «полночь» — 0:00:00):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c31e/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (data text);

insert into t values
  ("23.06.2015 10:30"),
  ("24.06.2015 10:45"),
  ("26.06.2015 12:15"),
  ("02.07.2015 11:24");
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t where str_to_date(data, "%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s")
  between "2015-06-23" and "2015-07-02"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c31e/5/0)**:

```
|             data |
|------------------|
| 23.06.2015 10:30 |
| 24.06.2015 10:45 |
| 26.06.2015 12:15 |
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Странно, но у меня не работает, версия мускула: 5.5.43.

Делаю запрос такой: 

`SELECT * FROM selling_list WHERE data between str_to_date("20.06.2015 00:00", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%i") and
  str_to_date("03.07.2015 00:00", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%i")`

Comment: с теми же данными, но уже ваш запрос (и под версию 5.5):  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24b84a/1 . ваш запрос вообще выполняется или даёт сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Выполняется, пишет: MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк). ( Запрос занял 0.0005 сек. )

Comment: и, кстати, а какой тип данных у столбца `data`? не строковый ли случайно?

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл указать. Тип text, понимаю что это обычная строка, но уже поздно наверно менять тип на DATE, DATETIME. Или нет? Как изменить тип без последствий?

Comment: тогда вам нужно обратное преобразование: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c31e/1 . но оно потребует значительно больше серверных ресурсов на приведённых примерах.

Comment: если такие выборки часты и на большом количестве строк, то я бы порекомендовал сделать рефакторинг кода (и в базе преобразовать данные).

Comment: Большое спасибо. Нет не часты, использую для кастомного бухгалтерского учета, для добавления продаж. Поэтому сервер потерпит. :) Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: кстати, если дата в строке указана в [понятном](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html) серверу `mysql` формате, то вызов «парсящей» функции не требуется: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c31e7/4

Comment: я переформулировал ответ, подчеркнув основные проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, поможет:

```
SELECT *
FROM selling_list
WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('22.06.2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
    AND STR_TO_DATE('30.06.2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
```